# Android Studio SharedPrerefernces is not working another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, sharedpreferences

I have created two activities SignUp and Login.
Also, I have SharedPreferences which get edittext value. When I call  SharedPreferences(**getNomre**) inside onCreate  It works but doesn't work as global variable. I want to declare a variable named mobileNomre for using put to Constant.mobile. How can I send Shared Preference value to Constant.mobile?

p.s: Acitivity code is too large. I noted some parts of them.
Thanks

SignUpActivity:

```
   public void SignUpWithEmail(View view) {
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();
    final String email = edtEmail.getText().toString();
    final String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
    final String name = edtName.getText().toString();
    final String mobile = edtMobile.getText().toString();


    Session.setNomre(getApplicationContext(),"nomreler",mobile);



                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                        .setDisplayName(name).build();

                assert user != null;
                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                }
                            }
                        });

                sendEmailVerification();
            } else {
                hideProgressDialog();

                try {
                    throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException | FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException | FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException invalidEmail) {
                    inputEmail.setError(invalidEmail.getMessage());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    inputEmail.setError(e.getMessage());
                }

            }

        }
    });
}
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG = "LoginActivity";
int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
String token;


String mobileNomre = Session.getNomre(getApplicationContext(),"nomreler","");


public static FirebaseAuth mAuth;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
TextView tvPrivacy, tvTest;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
public TextInputEditText edtEmail, edtPassword;
public TextInputLayout inputEmail, inputPass;


    public void UserSignUpWithSocialMedia(   final String mobileNomre,
                                        final String fCode,
                                      final String referCode,
                                      final String name,
                                      final String email,
                                      final String profile,
                                      final String type) {


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constant.QUIZ_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {



                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                if (obj.getString("error").equals("false")) {
                    JSONObject jsonobj = obj.getJSONObject("data");
                    if (!jsonobj.getString(Constant.status).equals(Constant.DE_ACTIVE)) {
                        Session.saveUserDetail(getApplicationContext(),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.userId),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.name),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.email),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.mobile),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.PROFILE), referCode);


                        User user = new User(
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.mobile),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.name),
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.email),
                                "0",
                                false,
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.PROFILE),
                                "0",
                                token,
                                jsonobj.getString(Constant.userId));


                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().
                                getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user).
                                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task1) {
                                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("type", "default");
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    } else
                        setSnackBarStatus();
                } else {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }

    }) {


        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(Constant.accessKey, Constant.accessKeyValue);
            params.put(Constant.userSignUp, "1");
            params.put(Constant.email, email);
            params.put(Constant.name, name);
            params.put(Constant.PROFILE, profile);
            params.put(Constant.fcmId, token);
            params.put(Constant.type, type);
            params.put(Constant.mobile, mobileNomre );

            params.put(Constant.REFER_CODE, referCode);
            params.put(Constant.FRIENDS_CODE, fCode);
            WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
            params.put(Constant.ipAddress, ip);
            System.out.println("---params social  " + params.toString());
            return params;

        }

    };

    // AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);

}
```

SharedPrereferences:

```
public class Session {
public static void setNomre(Context mContext, String key, String objString) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =
            mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name),
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
             editor.putString(key, objString);
             editor.commit();
}

public static String getNomre(Context mContext, final String key, final String defaultStr) {
    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getString(key, defaultStr);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your String `public static` to access it globally;

```
public static String mobileNomre = Session.getNomre(getApplicationContext(),"nomreler","");
```

Haven't tried but working around with below code can give you an idea,
We uses this method if we want to access any function of Activity1 in Activity2..

```
AnotherActivity anotheractivity = (AnotherActivity) this.getActivity();
```